# Do gpu cores switch tasks when they're done with one?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, c++-amp

I'm experimenting with c++ AMP, one thing thats unclear from MS documentation is this:

If I dispatch a `parallel_for_each` with an extent of say 1000, then that would mean that it spawns 1000 threads. If the gpu is unable to take on those 1000 threads at the same time, it completes them 300 at a time or 400 or whatever number it can do. Then there was some vague stuff on warps and tiles out of which I got this impression:

Regardless of how the threads are tiled together (or not at all), the whole group must finish before taking on new tasks so if the internally assigned group has the size of 128 and 30 of them finish, the 30 cores will idle until the other 98 are done too. Is that true? Also, how do I find out what this internal groups size is?

During my experimentation, it certainly appears to have some truth to it because assigning more even amounts of work to the threads seems to speed things up, even if there is slightly more work overall.

The reason I'm trying to figure it out is because I'm deciding whether or not to engage in another lengthy experiment that would be based on threads getting uneven amounts of work (sometimes by the factor of 10x) but all the threads would be independent so data wise, the cores would be free to pick up another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, the underlying execution model of AMP on GPU is the same as CUDA, OpenCL, Compute Shaders, etc. The only thing that changes is the naming of each concept. So if you feel that the AMP documentation is lacking, consider reading up on CUDA or OpenCL. Those are significantly more mature APIs and the knowledge you gain from them applies as well to AMP.

---

> If I dispatch a parallel_for_each with an extent of say 1000, then that would mean that it spawns 1000 threads. If the gpu is unable to take on those 1000 threads at the same time, it completes them 300 at a time or 400 or whatever number it can do.

Maybe. From the high-level view of `parallel_for_each`, you don't have to care about this. The threads may as well be executed sequentially, one at a time.

If you launch 1000 threads without specifying a tile size, the AMP runtime will choose a tile size for you, based on the underlying hardware. If you specify a tile size, then AMP will use that one.

GPUs are made of *multiprocessors* (in CUDA parlance, or *compute units* in OpenCL), each composed of a number of *cores*.

Tiles are assigned per multiprocessor: all threads within the same tile will be ran by the same multiprocessor, until all threads within that tile run to completion. Then, the multiprocessor will pick another available tile (if any) and run it, until all tiles are executed. Multiprocessors can execute multiple tiles simultaneously.

> if the internally assigned group has the size of 128 and 30 of them finish, the 30 cores will idle until the other 98 are done too. Is that true?

Not necessarily. As mentionned earlier, a multiprocessor may have multiple active tiles. It may therefore schedule threads from other tiles to remain busy.

> **Important note:** On GPU, threads are *not* executed on a granularity of 1. For example, NVIDIA hardware executes 32 threads at once.

To not make this answer needlessly lengthy, I encourage you to read up on the concept of *warp*.

Comment: A small correction: GPUs rapidly switch between threads, so a thread will typically not be completely executed by a single core and a single core will certainly not be pinned to a single thread. If you have 1000 cores, it's best to have many more than 1000 threads so that cores way switch tasks to cover latency.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted "One core is usually equal to one thread" above. Sorry if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU certainly won't run 1000 threads *at the same time*, but it also won't complete them 300 at a time.

It uses multithreading, which means that just like in a CPU, it will share run time among the 1000 threads allowing them to complete *seemingly* at the same time.

Keep in mind creating a lot of threads may be not interesting for several reasons. For instance, if you must complete all 1000 tasks in step 1 before doing step 2, you might aswell distribute them on a number of threads equal to the number of cores in your GPU and no more than that.

Using more threads than the number of cores only makes sense if you want to dispatch tasks that are not being waited on, or because you felt like doing your code this way is easier. But keep in mind thread management is time-costly too and may drag down your performance.